# Adding tooltip to line in Dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, dimple.js

I have created simplified network-style chart using Dimple's line plot as a basis. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cc1gpt2o/

```
  myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Entity");
  myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "Entity").addOrderRule("Keyword");
  var z = myChart.addMeasureAxis("z", "Size");
  z.overrideMin = 0;
  z.overrideMax = 200;
  myChart.addSeries("Keyword", dimple.plot.line);
  myChart.addSeries("Keyword", dimple.plot.bubble);
  myChart.draw();
```

However, line chart's tooltips only show when hovering over points. Since there are many overlapping points, it is difficult for the user to identify the lines and values. It would be best if the user could see tooltips while hovering over the lines between points.

I found a D3 method that bisects the line to display info about the points, but it seems too complex to apply to the setup I am working with: 
 - http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html

Before I wade too far into that solution, is there a simpler way to do this in Dimple? (--e.g., applying the circles' tooltip function onto paths?)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `series.addEventHandler('mouseover', handler)` only fires when you are over the points of the lines as far as I can tell, so no better than the default functionality. To target the lines themselves you'll have to use regular d3 :

```
chart.series[0].shapes.on('mouseover', function(e){
   //handle
   // `e` is data from line
   // d3.event has mouse position data
});
```

You can get information about the line itself (the data tied to that line) in that event object. Unfortunately it's not the same data as the `dimple.eventArgs` object, so you wouldn't be able to use the `dimple._showPointTooltip` or other tooltip methods (I don't think that would work anyway).

You can also get information about the x and y mouse positions from `d3.event` while inside that handler function. Combining the information from those two objects should let you position a custom tooltip at the current mouse position, and you could probably style it to look like the standard dimple tooltip.

What I'm not as sure of is how to then get the original corresponding value for where your mouse is. I believe it should be something like :

```
chart.series[0].y._scale.invert(d3.event.y);
```

but in my limited testing I couldn't get that to work correctly. Maybe this will be a helpful start in any case.